# Button on iOS/Android screen with app closed, Kivy

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy

I'm new to Kivy.
I would like to develop an app which displays a button on the iOS/Android screen all the time, like iPhone Home button,  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658.

Is it possible developing this type of application using Kivy?

Comment: I don't know anything about Kivy, but I don't think apple will allow any app to display content on the home screen. I could be wrong, but it seems highly unlikely apple would allow an app to change the ui experience.

Comment: You certainly can't do it on iOS in any language; You can only display elements when your app is running in the foreground.

Comment: Thx guys for fast response! I guessed so. Hope other answers come!